# How to Gracefully Turn Off Running Kafka Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a need to turn Kafka consumer on/off on the basis of some Database driven property. How can it be achieved.

one way that i have thought of is : throwing exception from consumer when consumer flag is turned off. and container factory config is defined as

```
factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler());
```

But it actively seeks the same message.

is there any way to turn heart-beat off and then on back again on demand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `stop()` and `start()` the listener container.

It appears you are using `@KafkaListener` since you are using a container factory.

In that case

```
@KafkaListener(id = "foo" ...)
```

and then use the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` bean ...

```
registry.getListenerContainer("foo").stop();
```

Comment: In my case I had to autowire  this bean as below to use the registry as Gary suggested
@Autowired
@Qualifier(KafkaListenerConfigUtils.KAFKA_LISTENER_ENDPOINT_REGISTRY_BEAN_NAME)
private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

Comment: @GaryRussell : Can you please explain the difference between unsubscribe vs close? Does the consumer rebalance happens in both? and if yes does it gives a performance impact over seeking a particular offset manually using seek method()?

Comment: You should not ask new, unrelated, questions in comments; it doesn't help people find questions and answers. Always ask a new question. `unsubscribe()` or `close()` will both cause a rebalance. The difference is you can subscribe/unsubscribe as many times as you want without completely tearing down the consumer. I am guessing, but I would expect seeks to be much more efficient than forcing 2 rebalances by unsubscribing and re-subscribing.

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks again, would make sure I post new question next time. Was just thinking it might not be of that much value to others.

Answer (score 3):

The Consumer has a few APIs to control its state:

- [`pause()`](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#pause-java.util.Collection-)/[`resume()`](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#resume-java.util.Collection-): Allows to stop/resume consusuming from a set of partitions. The Consumer stays subscribed (so no rebalance) but just does not fetch any new records until resumed
- [`unsubscribe()`](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#unsubscribe--): Allows to change consumer subscription, if not subscribed to anything, it will just stay connected to the cluster.

If you are "done" with the Consumer, you can also call [`close()`](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#close--) and start a new one when needed

Comment: Could you point to some resources about internal working of pause() and resume(). for e.g is it like request to leave consumer from its group in pause() and then request to join consumer group in resume().

Comment: No, `pause()` just stops the consumption of the given partitions but the consumer stays in the group (no rebalance). Consumers only leave their group on `close()` or when they are kicked if they failed to heartbeat

Comment: @MickaelMaison : Can you please explain the difference between unsubscribe vs close? Does the consumer rebalance happens in both? and if yes does it gives a performance impact over seeking a particular offset manually using seek method()?

Comment: `close()` fully disconnects the client while `unsubscribe()` keep the client connected. If the client stays closed or unsubscribed, a rebalance will be triggered to reassign their partitions to other members. But there are a number of nuances that are a bit hard to explain in a comment, especially since Kafka 2.3 with static membership (http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#static_membership).